# How to change the application menu name in PyQt4 on OS X

Tags: macos, pyqt4, pyside

I'm porting a PyQt4 (PySide) application that I wrote for Linux and Windows to OS X, menus seem to be otherwise OK out of the box (i.e. `Help` menu that only has `About` in it is magically moved to the "main menu" and a `File` menu is created just fine, but the "main" menu is titled `Python` instead of `Application name`.

I call `self.setWindowTitle("Appname")` in `MainWindow.__init__()` and `self.setApplicationName("Appname")` in `Application.__init__()` but the result is this:

[image: Screenshot of menu bar]

How can I fix this? - Preferably in a way that my app still looks the same as it did before on Windows & Linux.

Comment: Can you give a little sample? I'm not sure what you mean exactly.

Comment: @Jeff - need to see more code or is the edit enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it looks like Mac does something different than the other OS systems.  I don't have a Mac so I can't really test it out but I think on a Mac the QMainWindow.menuBar() function does not return the application wide menu bar. You might try creating menubar like.

`menubar = QtGui.MenuBar()`

that has no parent.

I'm getting this information from the following links.

[From the documents](http://www.pyside.org/docs/pyside/PySide/QtGui/QMenuBar.html#qmenubar-on-mac-os-x)

[Deploying an Application on Mac OS X](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/deployment-mac.html)

Also, it looks like the file `Info.plist` in "The Bundle" section of the second link is where the application name would live.

I'm sorry I can't be of more help but I hope this information will help you.  Good luck!